# Spring data jpa update (save) wont' update entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have the following method for update an entity:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateMethod(){

     foo(); //

     // data processing...

     repository.save(entity);
}
```

The issue is that if foo() is executed the entity is not updated. I also tried in this way:

```
fooService.foo();
entityService.updateMethod();
```

with same results.

But if foo() is not executed all work as expected, the entity is updated.

Am I missing something here?

**Update**:

Basically what foo() does is query some data `repository.findBy....();` then uses the results to perform some business logic and then return true if everything is OK otherwise it will return false.

The update method modify the entity if foo returns true. I'm modifying the entity using reflection:

```
 Entity entity = repository.findOne(id);
Field[] field = Entity.Class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field: fields){
    if (map.containsKey(field.getName())){
        setattr(entity, field.getName(), map.get(field.getName());
}
}

private boolean setattr(Object object, String fieldName, Object fieldValue){
         Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
            while (clazz != null) {
                try {
                    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(object, fieldValue);
                    return true;
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend enabling logs via `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` and checking the queries.

Comment: Maybe there is some exception being thrown in `foo`? Anyway, I think you should share some more code.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I have logging enabled, and I do not see the update query when foo() is executed, otherwise the update query is issued.

Comment: Remember `hibernate.show_sql=true` and maybe `hibernate.format_sql=true`, too.

Comment: @Càphêđen both are enabled.

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: @JuanJO Have you got `@Transactional` in calling method? Spring won't flush the changes until the current transaction gets over.

Comment: Check if that transaction is committed or rolled back. Then traceback why the transaction is rolled back, some exceptions maybe.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I have tried with and without `@Transactional` and neither worked.